# How to add citation in latex?

Tags: bibliographies

I am new to latex. I am trying to add bibliography using .bib file. I have tried using `\cite{}` command to add the citation. But when I compile it it is showing question marks. Can someone tell me how can I add a citation in latex.
I have used the following commands:

```
\bibliography{references} 
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

`references.bib` is the name of the .bib file

[image]

Comment: After running LaTeX, did you run BibTeX followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: Hello @Mico, Thak you for your quick reply. I am not using any bibtex file. Just like a normal text file I have created a .bib file and i called it in main script.

Comment: Please consult the posting [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5001).